# Acesso a dados EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dapper

Dúvida acesso a dados `efcore`

Tenho uma tabela com muitos campos, estou usando **EF Core** para acesso, é possível retornar somente os campos que vou realmente usar?

Ex. em uma listagem, preciso do ID e Título, porém o EF sempre traz tudo, uns 30 campos que a tabela possui, prevejo que isso vai causar trafego desnecessário.

Dapper seria uma opção? com dapper consigo retorar apenas algumas colunas da tabela e mapear para minha classe de domínio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tenho uma tabela com muitos campos, estou usando EF Core para acesso,
>   é possível retornar somente os campos que vou realmente usar?

Supondo que você tem a seguinte entidade:

```
public class MinhaEntidade
{
    public int Propiedade1 { get; set; }
    public int Propiedade2 { get; set; }
    public int Propiedade3 { get; set; }
    public int Propiedade4 { get; set; }
    public int Propiedade5 { get; set; }
    public int Propiedade6 { get; set; }
    public int Propiedade7 { get; set; }
    public int Propiedade8 { get; set; }
    public int Propiedade9 { get; set; }
}
```

Você pode fazer algo como nesse exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        var entidade = new List<MinhaEntidade>();

        //Preencher alguns valores aleatórios
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            entidade.Add(
                new MinhaEntidade{
                    Propiedade1 = rnd.Next(),
                    Propiedade2 = rnd.Next(),
                    Propiedade3 = rnd.Next(),
                    Propiedade4 = rnd.Next(),
                    Propiedade5 = rnd.Next(),
                    Propiedade6 = rnd.Next(),
                    Propiedade7 = rnd.Next(),
                    Propiedade8 = rnd.Next(),
                    Propiedade9 = rnd.Next()
                }
            );
        }

        //Seleciona apenas 3 itens da MinhaEntidade para um objeto anonimo
        var teste = entidade.Select(q => new
            {
                propX = q.Propiedade1,
                propY = q.Propiedade4,
                propZ = q.Propiedade9
            }).ToList();

        //Imprime os itens selecionados:
        foreach(var item in teste)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", item.propX, item.propY, item.propZ));
        }
    }
}
```

[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gmv1LH)

> Dapper seria uma opção? com dapper consigo retorar apenas algumas
>   colunas da tabela e mapear para minha classe de domínio ?

Sim, com `Dapper` também é possível, você pode retornar um `dynamic` com apenas os itens que quer:

```
var resultado = conexaoBD.Query("Select coluna1, coluna3, coluna7 from MinhaTabela");
//Retorna uma lista de objetos dinâmicos  eliminando a necessidade de definir objeto.
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} ", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3");
```

Comment: Acho que a ideia é essa, mas de fato os dados não estão trafegando na rede? Parece que tudo veio do banco, porém só foi populado alguns campos.
Ou nesse caso somente as propriedades 1,4 e 9 são retornadas do banco para a aplicação?

Comment: A dúvida se da devido ao fato de existirem campos com um grande volume de texto (notícias), porém na listagem só preciso do título e não do texto (corpo da notícia). caso eu liste 100 notícias em uma página (apenas ex.) poderia trazer do banco para a aplicação um volume muito menor se conseguir trafegar apenas ID e Título...

Comment: @AlexandrePreviatti, no exemplo, no trecho que está assim ."Select(q => new..." o select traz do banco apenas os campos que você especificou mesmo. O que você não pode é fazer um select do seu 'objeto completo' pra só depois selecionar os campos que quer. Você consegue ver o select gerado pelo EF pra confirmar isso, mas acho que não é escopo dessa resposta.